# sorting list of dict by multiple keys in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dictionary`

```
data = [{'name' : 'messi', 'place': 'barcelona'}, {'name': 'salah', 'place': 'liverpool'}, 
        {'name': 'neymar', 'place': 'paris'}, {'name': 'suarez', 'place': 'barcelona'}]
```

I want to sort this list of dict by multiple `keys` place in ascending and name in descending order

I know how to sort the list of dict with multiple fields, **both in ascending**

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x['name'], x['place']))
```

But I am not sure how to achieve one field in ascending and another in descending( both are `str` type)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to sort twice, first by `name` in descending order, and then by `place` in ascending order, relying on the fact that python sort is stable, so that if two entries have the same `place` value, their ordering will be preserved in the second sort (so `name` will remain sorted descending):

```py
sorted(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['name'], reverse=True), key=lambda x: x['place'])
```

Output

```
[
 {'name': 'suarez', 'place': 'barcelona'},
 {'name': 'messi', 'place': 'barcelona'},
 {'name': 'salah', 'place': 'liverpool'},
 {'name': 'neymar', 'place': 'paris'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to first sort by name or place, but anyway, this is from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html
I added neymar's Barca days to show how it works

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
data = [{'name' : 'messi', 'place': 'barcelona'}, {'name': 'salah', 'place': 'liverpool'}, 
        {'name': 'neymar', 'place': 'paris'}, {'name': 'neymar', 'place': 'barcelona'}, {'name': 'suarez', 'place': 'barcelona'}]
def comparer(x,y):
    if x['name']>y['name']:
        return 1
    if x['name']<y['name']:
        return -1
    if x['place']<y['place']:
        return 1
    if x['place']>y['place']:
        return -1
    return 0
sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(comparer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would want to use an extra module, but, using `pandas`, you can make the solution explicit (some pre-processing is needed to re-organise your data though).

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'name' : 'messi', 'place': 'barcelona'}, {'name': 'salah', 'place': 'liverpool'}, 
        {'name': 'neymar', 'place': 'paris'}, {'name': 'suarez', 'place': 'barcelona'}]

data_dict = dict()
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in data_dict:
            data_dict[k].append(v)
        else:
            data_dict[k] = [v]
#print(data_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
#print(df)

df.sort_values(['place', 'name'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

The output will be:

```bash
     name      place
0  suarez  barcelona
1   messi  barcelona
2   salah  liverpool
3  neymar      paris
```